# How do I find a user in Active Directory using their nativeguid in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm running into a problem where running a DirectorySearcher isn't always returning a result successfully. For instance, I'll send in my manager's GUID using the following method to convert the string (NativeGuid):

```
public static string Guid2OctetString(string objectGuid)
{
    System.Guid guid = new Guid(objectGuid);
    byte[] byteGuid = guid.ToByteArray();
    string queryGuid = "";
    foreach (byte b in byteGuid)
    {
        queryGuid += @"\" + b.ToString("x2");
    }
    return queryGuid;
}
```

This supposedly converts the guid string into something usable by Active Directory. When I run my manager's `NativeGuid` through this, I get a result. But then in the next step of the application, I run one of the directReports' Guids through in the same way but get no results. The user DOES exist and I can get the entry if i pull the `DirectoryEntry`, but I don't want the full entry as it is too slow to process. I need to be able to narrow the fields using the `DirectorySearcher` to speed this thing up. Any ideas why I'm getting goose egg on the directory search on some users but not others?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, YourGuid.ToString());

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually familiar with it. However, the set of default properties are limited. I need direct access to the manager, all direct reports, group memberships, and photos that are all located in AD. It doesn't seem that this helper class has those properties and I would have to extend the class to get them. It feels like it would be easier to just figure out what's going on with the GUID lookup using searcher!